# What are the standard hypothesis tests in any type of regression?

Tags: regression

In general, what the the standard hypothesis tests in all types of regression? We get some coefficients and then test the hypotheses that these coefficients are significant (i.e not equal to $0$)? For example, in logistic regression the p-value indicates that the regression coefficients are significant or not? Likewise with linear regression?

> Question: Suppose coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are significant in linear regression. Can we deduce anything about the significance of $\beta_0+\beta_1$? What about $\beta_0= \beta_1$?

Comment: Indeed, softwares return the $p$-value for $H_0:\{\theta=0\}$ for each parameter $\theta$ of the model.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: Is there a way to test for example $H_0: \theta_1+\theta_2 = 2$?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @proton For a Gaussian linear regression model it is easy to test about any linear combination of the parameters.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: How about for other types of regression.

Comment: @proton I think this is also possible with standard softwares, for standard "simple" types of regressions (without random effects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a contrast matrix $L$ and a vector of parameters $\beta$. Then test any kind of linear combination of the parameters using the null hypothesis, $H_0:L\beta=d$. You can use a Wald test or a Likelihood Ratio Test (LRT) for testing your $H_0$.

Comment: What if you want to test $H_0: \frac{\beta_0}{\beta_1} = 1$ vs $H_a: \frac{\beta_0}{\beta1} \neq 1$?

Comment: It is all the same as $H_0:\beta_0-\beta_1=0$, isn't it? More over you could also test $H_0:\frac{\beta_0}{d\beta_1}=1$ by constructing a contrast matrix $L$ such that $H_0:\beta_0-d\beta_1=0$.